# How to check in which line of text the word is

Tags: java

I'm doing an exercise where I need to count how many times a word appears on a text and I also need to print in which line the words are present.

Text example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

This is my method to find and count every word:

```
public void findWords() {
    try {
        File myObj = new File("path\\text.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String text = myReader.nextLine();
            final String lowerText = text.toLowerCase();
            final String[] split = lowerText.split("\\W+");
            System.out.println("Output: ");
            for (String s : split) {
                if (s == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                    final boolean sameWorld = s.equals(split[i]);
                    if (sameWorld) {
                        count = count + 1;
                        split[i] = null;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(s + " " + count);
            }
        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The current output is something like this:

```
Output:
lorem 1
ipsum 1
dolor 1
sit 1
amet 1
consectetur 1
adipiscing 1
....
```

And I want it to show in which line the word is like:

```
Output:
lorem 1 - line 1
ipsum 1 - line 1
...
```

To make it clearer, the word "ut" appears 3 times in 2 different lines and the output should look like this:

```
 ut 3 - line 1 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to create an object to handle the word. It could have a String to represent the text of the word and an array of ints representing the lines it appears on and then an int representing the frequency of it's occurances in the text. As for tracking the line you could keep track of the line you're on with a counter variable inside the while loop maybe?

If you went that route You might be better using a hashmap and treeset to store the word objects and then print them out based on some order.

Comment: For this exercise, I'm not allowed to use a hashmap or anything similar.

Comment: Ahh okay. Perhaps I'm overcomplicating it. What data structures are you supposed to be using?

Comment: I can use pretty much everything else than "maps", right now what I'm doing is just reading the text file line by line and saving the words on an Array excluding duplicates and counting how many equal words there are. My problem at the moment is: how to do the same thing but reading the whole file at once so the method can really count the total number of times a word is in the text and how can I print every line every word is present.

Comment: Are you allowed to use sets? If so you could create an object for each word instance and add them to the set, then on each time you further encounter them, increment a field inside the word object to track the frequency. You'd have to include a string or int array to track the lines they occured on. This post gives a fairly good demonstration of a similar idea but with maps instead of sets https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48198/count-frequency-of-words-in-a-given-file

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you were allowed to use Maps, this is about how it would be done. Being very familiar and comfortable with how and when to use List, HashMap (aka dictionaries), and HashSet -- often in combination -- is one of the most fundamental skills in programming, in my opinion.

```
public class SO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Integer> wordToCount = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Set<Integer>> wordToLines = new HashMap<>();

        File myObj = new File("path\\text.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            lineNumber++;
            String text = myReader.nextLine();
            if (text.isBlank()) {
                continue;
            }
            final String lowerText = text.toLowerCase();
            final String[] split = lowerText.split("\\W+");
            for (String word : split) {
                Integer count = wordToCount.get(word);
                if (count == null) {
                    count = 0;
                }
                wordToCount.put(word, count + 1);

                Set<Integer> lines = wordToLines.get(word);
                if (lines == null) {
                    lines = new TreeSet<>();
                    wordToLines.put(word, lines);
                }
                lines.add(lineNumber);
            }
        }
        myReader.close();

        for (String word : wordToCount.keySet()) {
            Set<Integer> lines = wordToLines.get(word);
            List<String> linesStrings = lines.stream().map(String::valueOf).toList();
            String linesStr = String.join(", ", linesStrings);
            int wordCount = wordToCount.get(word);
            System.out.printf("%-20s %-3d %s\n", word, wordCount, linesStr);
        }
    }
}
```